# Electric stove wiring

Tags: electrical

Help!

I had the bright idea of changing my electric stove top, it looked simple enough.

I have 220V coming from my wall with one green, one bare, one hot black and one black wire.

From my stove-top I have one green, one bare, one red, two black and one white wire.

- I connected the two greens & the bare wire together.
- I connected the two black wires together.
- I connected the one black hot to the red hot wire.

But now I don't know what to do with the white wire coming from my stove.

The stove works great. The problem is that I have a white wire that I don't know what to connect it to. I may be wrong but I think this is a common wire and not a hot wire. To what set of wires do I connect it?

Comment: First:  Don't run your stove until you figure this out!  Second: how many wires are going to your outlet?  Your description makes it look like there are four, but two of them are black?  "one green, one bare, one hot black and one black wire."  This is very odd.  It should be a white, black, red, and bare.  Also, what country are you in?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you say you have "one hot black and one black wire" from the wall? What does this mean?

If all you have from the wall is two hots and a ground you CANNOT use this circuit for this cooktop. This is a straight 240V circuit with no neutral.

According to your description your cooktop requires a 4-wire 120/240V circuit.

Answer (score -2):

You did fine.   Don't need white.
Does the stove temp match the thermometer you got at BB&B to put inside?

Answer (score -2):

In a 220V circuit, there is no neutral since the 220V is obtained via two 120V (hot) legs.

It is common for a neutral to be included when connecting a stove or oven because often the appliance will have some components that run at 120V (especially stoves that provide a 120V outlet on them).

So if your new appliance does not require this, place a wire nut over the unused connector and neatly tuck it into the electrical box.

EDIT: Now that the question has been formatted to be a bit more readable, I see that your appliance has the neutral and not the outlet, so in this case, your appliance **does** require the neutral.  If your outlet does not have a neutral, you will need to run a new cable that includes a neutral.  It might be best to contact a licensed electrician to complete this for you.